# jquery footer navbar shifts upwards upon tap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile application using PhoneGap. The application has a single page with a jQuery Mobile navbar as a footer. The problem I am facing is that when I tap on any area of the screen, the navbar shifts upwards a distance equivalent to its height, leaving a whitespace in the original position. if I tap it again, it goes back to normal.

My code for the navbar:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a onClick="navRegister();" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="e" data-icon="gear">
          <h5> Register </h5>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a onClick="exitFromApp();" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="e" data-icon="back">
          <h5>  Exit  </h5>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What may be the reason for this?

Comment: Add `data-tap-toggle=false` to footer div.

Comment: i tried that. not working. i think it works with jQuery mobile 1.1 version. i am using 1.3

Comment: It works for all versions. Change `h5` with `p` and see if behavior changes. Also by adding toggle false.

Comment: behaviour does not change by changing p from h5

Comment: try data-id="persistent" to footer div